# How to get output of the ffmpeg to the var and upload it using curl?

Tags: curl, ffmpeg, telegram

how to get the output of the ffmpeg to the var and upload it using curl, like here

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f avi pipe:1 | cat > out | curl -F document=@"$out" https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=<chat_id>
```

In this command **test.mp4** is input file and out put is **out**

Here I am trying to store output of **ffmpeg** to a var named `out` and then trying to upload it to telegram directly but nothing happen. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual way of using `ffmpeg`. I think there might be a way of using `stdout` as the output of `ffmpeg` command but it is a dirty way if any!
You should set the output file of `ffmpeg` command and then send this file by `curl`. Then you can delete the file if you want. You can put these commands in a `.sh` or `.bat` file and run it using a single command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f avi out.mp4
curl -T out.mp4 https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=<chat_id>
rm out.mp4
```

Comment: but in that case its taking much more time means it would be easy if ffmpeg directly upload it to server and fast too. i know its dirty way but it could save much more time and space too.

Comment: You should note that when you are uploading a file you should provide the `Content-Length` of the request body, so if you pipe the output using `cat`, the `curl` command needs to detect the length of the `cat` output to populate the headers of the upload request and this means it must read it to the end and then it should read it again to create the request body!
I suggest you create a simple program and use `stdout` of the first command into a `byte[]` and then use this __in-memory variable__ for your API call